# Get results from SELECT then UPDATE it into the database MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the time average by using this command in PHP :

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(PunchInTime))) as Average from AverageOnTime;
```

so is this code below correct to combine update and avg:

```
UPDATE table_3_2020 SET pastTime = SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(currentTime))) WHERE id = '1'
```

I have two requests:

1. I want to UPDATE another column with the average, so how can I do
   that?
2. When I use the above SELECT I got the HH:MM but I just want the
   minutes only without the hours.

Comment: Almost anything you do in a `select` can be done in an `update`.

Comment: @user3783243 code you check the question again I updated it and added a code, check if I'm correct or no.

Comment: This looks like poor design. Do not have separate tables for (presumably) each month of the year. As an alternative, consider partitioning, if you must, but don't rush to partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
UPDATE table_3_2020 SET pastTime = (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(PunchInTime))) as Average from AverageOnTime) WHERE id = '1';
```